# Парсер контента на сайт Вордпресс

Tags: веб-программирование, парсер

Стоит задача брать заголовки и картинки статьи с нескольких источников, и выкладывать их у себя на сайте. То есть при нажатии на заголовок, должна открываться новая вкладка с этой статьей.

И это надо реализовать на движке вордпресс.

Анологичный сайт  [www.newsline.kg](http://newsline.kg)

Как это реализовать? может есть полезные ссылки на статьи и тому подобное.

Comment: Aidar Aibekov, а где вопрос?

Comment: Как это реализовать? может есть полезные ссылки на статьи и тому подобное.

Comment: @AidarAibekov не нужно задавать повторно один и тот же вопрос. Если вам не ответили на предыдущий, постарайтесь улучшить его, добавив в него уточняющую информацию

Comment: Хорошо. Приму к сведению. Я же задаю вопросы не просто так, а потому что я забрел в тупик. Вот уже две недели занимаюсь этим. Никак не могу прийти к оптимальому решению. А так спасибо за совет. Постараюсь в следующий раз расписать задачу.

Comment: @AidarAibekov здесь задают конкретные технические вопросы, вроде "Какую библиотеку на php лучше всего использовать для парсинга сайта" или "Как сделать отображение новости в окне на wordpress". На вопросы типо "Как сделать сайт на wordpress" или "Как сделать парсер" написаны десятки тысяч статей и сделаны сотни обучающих курсов на разных языках. И ответ на эти вопросы явно не укладывается в формат SO.